# Accessing the assigned value of a Javascript property in an object function

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a javascript object that has a property which is assigned a value after the object has been instantiated. I then want to use the value in a function of the object. Instead of the newly assigned value however, the function is only seeing the initial value of the property (i.e. null)

```
var _protocolData = new function () {

    var test = null;
    var getTest = function () {

        return test;
    };

    return {
        Test: test,
        GetTest: getTest
    };
};
//
// assign the new property value
_protocolData.Test = "New Value";
//
// I expect the dialog box to be populated with "New Value".
alert(_protocolData.GetTest());  // alert box is empty (null)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your function closes over the *variable* `test` and that's what you're using in your function. You're not using the *property* `Test` at all.

To use the *property* `Test` (because you've given it the capital letter when making the property):

```
var getTest = function () {

    return this.Test;
    //     ^^^^^^
};
```

Using the *property* requires giving the object reference (`this.` in the above), and the property name has a capital `T` rather than a lower-case one.

---

Note that your object, as quoted, is much more complicated than it needs to be. You can write it like this:

```
var _protocolData = {

    Test:    null,
    GetTest: function () {

        return this.Test;
    }
};
```

Comment: I am familiar with the Literal syntax for javascript objects however, I like the notion of being able to define private variables/functions that the Revelaing Module Pattern provides. Using the "this" with the PROPERTY name as you described was indeed the solution!! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a setter:

```
var _protocolData = new function () {

    var test = null;
    var getTest = function () {
        return test;
    };
    var setTest = function(t) {
        test = t;   
    }

    return {
        Test: test,
        GetTest: getTest,
        SetTest: setTest
    };
};
// assign the new property value
_protocolData.SetTest("New Value");
```

Note: modern JavaScript also have actual getters and setters, which you could create with [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

Comment: Getters/Setters for Javascript!? Nice! :) This is news to me!! I will defnitely look into it more.  Thanks for some great guidance!